# Double Alert Windows

Tags: javascript, forms, alert

I am getting double Alert prompts for a single form: The alert pops up the first time, then when I click OK, the same one pops open again. I think my code should do the alert once when it hits "else  window.alert(sameWarning) and the stop when it reaches "return false()"; but it seems return false() is causing the alert twice. Maybe because I have two forms on one page; yet, they have two separate function names ("signinForm()" and "saveSignUp()")and call two separate forms (forms[0] and forms[1])?  I think my code is correct, but I can't figure it out at this point. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//FIRST FUNCTION FOR FORMS[0]
function signinForm(){

        // var sameWarning = "The required fields were not submitted for the following error(s).  \n \n";
        var warningLogin = "The following field(s) require an entry: \n \n";
        var sameWarning = warningLogin;

        var userName = document.forms[0].userName.value;
        var pswd = document.forms[0].pswd.value;

        if(userName == ""){ 
        sameWarning += " - First Name \n";
        }

        if(pswd == ""){ 
        sameWarning += " - Password \n";
        }

        if (warningLogin == sameWarning){ 
            return true; 
            }

        else  { 
            window.alert(sameWarning);  
        }
    return false;   
   }

//SECOND FUNCTION CALL FOR FORMS[1] 
function saveSignUp(){

        // var warning = "The required fields were not submitted for the following error(s).  \n \n";
        var warning = "The following field(s) require an entry: \n \n";
        var same = warning;

        var firstName = document.forms[1].firstName.value;
        var lastName = document.forms[1].lastName.value;
        var email = document.forms[1].email.value;
        var phone = document.forms[1].phoneNumber.value;

        if(firstName == ""){ 
        //firstName.style.backgroundColor="red";
        warning += " - First Name \n";
        }

        if(lastName == ""){ 
        warning += " - Last Name \n";
        }

        if(email == ""){ 
        warning += " - Email \n";
        }

        if(phone == ""){ 
        warning += " - Work Phone \n";
        }

        if(phone < 5 ){
            warning += " - Must be a numberssss \n";
            }

        if (warning == same){
            return true; 
        } 

        else  { 
            alert(warning);         
        }
    return false;
   }

</script>
```

HTML

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return signinForm();" action="" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username/Email" name="userName">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pswd" id="pswd">
    <input type="submit" onclick="signinForm();" value="Sign In">
</form>
<h1>Sign Up!</h1>
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return saveSignUp()" action="" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phoneNumber">
    <input type="submit" onclick="saveSignUp();" class="button wide" value="Request an Account">
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you call `signinForm();` twice.

Remove one of these listeners

`onclick="signinForm();"`

`onsubmit="return signinForm()"`

When you click on submit button you call `signinForm();`. And because it is a `submit` button, it will trigger the `onsubmit` event, and call `return signinForm()`

Comment: Is onsubmit a special event handler just for button type=submit? Is there a preference among developers to use onclick vs. onsubmit?

Answer (score 1):

When you click submit, first it fires the click event (calling your function), then it fires a submit event (calling your function again).  Just remove the onclick for the submit buttons.

Comment: That worked! Thanks you.  I didn't know there was an order of precedence for method calls over submit calls.  So, the onclick goes first, then it automatically fires the submit call to the function too?

Comment: There's no difference between onsubmit and onclick, they are just ways to register event handlers on an element.  So "saveSignUp()" gets called when you click the input, and "return saveSignUp()" gets called when you submit the form.  It just so happens that `input type="submit"` is a special kind of button that automatically submits the form.